# How to remove axle and bearings from a B'TWIN Triban Aero wheel

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, wheels, hub, axle

I have a [B'TWIN Triban Aero rear wheel](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/triban-aero-road-bike-wheel-rear-id_8379881.html) and am trying to replace the sealed bearings. After removing the end caps and a DS rubber seal I can see the ends of the bearings, at this point I assumed that the axle could be removed by tapping with a hammer, however with a reasonable amount of force it didn't move. Do I just need to be more aggressive or is there a further step before the axle and bearings can be removed from the hub?

[image: Manufacturer image of assembled hub.]
The assembled hub.

[image: The drive side bearing, seated within the freehub.]
The DS with the bearing seated within the freehub.

[image: Non drive side bearing.]
NDS bearing and axle.

Comment: any news on this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Looks like press-fit bearings from here.

Comment: OP - Any updates?  This question seems to be popular.

Comment: I'd try using a press to push the inner axle out. Chances are that'll get the axle out. (Disclaimer: if there's something going on we can't see this might destroy the hub, but thankfully the wheel doesn't look too expensive)

Comment: @Criggie Unfortunately it turned out that the bearings were not going, instead the hub had cracked! The wheel was replaced under warranty by Decathlon (a warranty replacement itself), so I never did remove the axle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say 100%, but this looks like the sort of hub where you just need to smack the ends of the axle sufficiently hard to drive the bearings out. Make sure you're bracing the wheel by holding the hub and not the rim.

Answer (score 2):

Nathan Knutson is right!

follow this "Checking the bearings on Specialized Hi-Lo hubs" guide

http://t3mppu.kapsi.fi/2017/02/05/checking-the-bearings-on-specialized-hi-lo-hubs/